# In terms of atmospheric pressure, why do pressure systems move and what factors affect the general pressure of an area?

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere, climate, pressure, air-currents

With very limited background in the physics of air and weather, this question occurred to me for no particular reason. With that in mind, a simplified answer would be much appreciated.

This weatherman's account is all that I have to go by: https://youtu.be/aiYyCurh_SU

Although, it was not clear to me as to why we have converging and diverging air aloft. I have a few other minor questions but I think that which was stated in the Question Header will make things clearer.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It is a topic for a book, not for a limited answer on a Q/A site. For starters, see [Synoptic scale meteorology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synoptic_scale_meteorology) // If you consider an eddy in water analogy, the eddy moves because water moves away from places where it is and to places where it is not.